# Looking to combine a PC, Laptop and 2 monitors using a single keyboard and mouse

Tags: laptop, keyboard, multiple-monitors, mouse

I have an HP Pavilion laptop for work, Two 2k monitors, a Gaming desktop, keyboard and mouse on a single desk.  I'm looking to connect 2 monitors to the PC for gaming and also use both for dual screens for my laptop (want to keep laptop closed while working to minimize space)  I'd like to connect both monitors via DP to the desktop and using HDMI to the laptop, again sharing the keyboard and mouse.  There is no thunderbolt connection on the laptop unfortunately.  What would be the best means to combine this environment?  Do I need some sort of universal docking station perhaps?

Comment: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/garage/wall-of-fame/mouse-without-borders/

Comment: what outputs does the laptop have? There are plenty of docks that can do two 2k monitors. mouse without borders is probably the best option, but you can get a kvm if you want to switch audio, video, and other usb stuff at the same time

Comment: Laptop is minimal.  USB, usb-c (not thunderbolt but SS) and an HDMI

Comment: You can get a straight usb-c to hdmi converter or a full usb-c dock (more expensive) in order to get another hdmi output. You may *need* to close the laptop for both monitors to work properly, depending on the exact model of laptop and whether it supports three displays